# segmentation fault while running the programme

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have written code for parsing a string into words. Here is code. Can any one help here to fix the segmentation fault error during run time?

Calling fun :

```
int main()
{
    int count = 0, i;           // count to hold numbr of words in the string line.

    char buf[MAX_LENTHS];   // buffer to hold the string

    char *options[MAX_ORGS]; // options to hold the words that we got after parsing.

    printf("enter string");

    scanf("%s",buf);

    count = parser(buf,options); // calling parser

    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i)

    printf("option %d is %s", i, options[i]);

    return 0;  
}
```

Called function:

```
int parser(char str[], char *orgs[])
{
    char temp[1000];//(char *)malloc(strlen(str)*sizeof(char));
    int list = 0;

    strcpy(temp, str);

    *orgs[list]=strtok(str, " \t ");

    while(((*orgs[list++]=strtok(str," \t"))!=NULL)&&MAX_ORGS>list)
        list++;

    printf("count =%d",list);

    return list;

}
```

Note : I'm trying to learn C these days, can any one help to get a good tutorial (pdf) or site to learn these strings with pointers, and sending string to functions as arguments?

Comment: Compile with -g for debuging symbols then run it in GDB, it will tell you what line it segfaulted at.

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `char *options[MAX_ORGS]` - it just contains uninitialised (i.e. garbage) pointers.

Comment: @Srinivas Thanneeru, I learned C using [The Joy of C](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Joy-C-Programming/dp/047112933X/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1374074843&sr=8-5&keywords=%22the+joy+of+c%22) but I guess it's an old text now (if revised). £101 on Amazon! Or £5 used... Also, [Herb Schildt's Complete Reference](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Complete-Reference-Osborne/dp/0072121246/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1374075052&sr=1-3&keywords=Herb+Schildt+C+The+Complete+Reference) is a really good reference and provides excellent function usage examples - check out `strtok`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int parser(char str[], char *orgs[]){
    int list=0;

    orgs[list]=strtok(str, " \t\n");
    while(orgs[list]!=NULL && ++list < MAX_ORGS)
        orgs[list]=strtok(NULL," \t\n");
    printf("count = %d\n",list);
    return list;
}
int main(){
    int count=0,i;
    char buf[MAX_LENTHS];
    char *options[MAX_ORGS];
    printf("enter string: ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);//input include space character
    count=parser(buf,options);
    for(i=0;i<count;++i)
        printf("option %d is %s\n",i,options[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not downvoted but I guess you should add a sentence explaining what have you done to fix it. What was the problem, etc.

Comment: OK If for lack of explanation rather than a flaw in the program.

Comment: I guess, I haven't checked. But I had to do a diff (with my eyes) in order to find the differences. That's not very helpful for those only looking to avoid to do the same mistakes (if we don't know what the mistake was nor why).

Comment: Downvoting for the same reason. Please explain your answer.

Comment: umm, never enough to commentary exaggerated. Then, you will know (mere misunderstanding) for strtok. I think that it is clear reason for the improvement from the comparison because it was going to improve with respect to original as possible.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `strtok` wrong.

(It is generally best to not use `strtok` at all, for all its problems and pitfalls.)

If you *must* use it, the proper way to use `strtok` is to call it ONCE with the string you want to "tokenize",
then call it again and again with NULL as an indication to continue parsing the original string.

---

I also think you're using the `orgs` array wrong.
Change this assignment

```
*orgs[list++]=strtok(str, " \t ");
```

to this:

```
orgs[list++]=strtok(str, " \t ");
```

Because `orgs` is an array of character-pointers.
`orgs[x]` is a character-pointer, which matches the return-type of `strtok`

Instead, you are referring to `*orgs[x]`, which is just a character.
So you are trying to do:

```
[character] = [character-pointer];
```

which will result in *"very-bad-things™"*.

---

Finally, note that you are incrementing list ***twice*** each time through your loop.
So basically you're only filling in the even-elements, leaving the odd-elements of orgs uninitialized.

Only increment list ***once*** per loop.

Basically, you want this:

```
orgs[list++] = strtok(str, " \t ");

while(( (orgs[list++] = strtok(NULL," \t")) !=NULL) && MAX_ORGS > list)
    /* do nothing */;
```

---

**PS** You allocate space for `temp`, and `strcpy` into it.
But then it looks like you never use it.
  Explain what `temp` is for, or remove it.

Comment: +1 but in your last code sample `list` must be incremented after storing the result of first `strtok` and before storing result of second.

Comment: thanks to all. and can any one help to know a good book or some e-copy to learn all these thing regarding pointers ..

Comment: thank you sir  @Ingo Leonhardt. and i fixed all things what you said here, but the thing is im getting same word instead of different words in the string, eg : HI IM MASTER.o/p : HI HI HI HI .. since im using while(((*orgs[list++]=strtok(str," \t"))!=NULL)&&MAX_ORGS>list).  and i tried to use while(((*orgs[list++]=strtok(NULL," \t"))!=NULL)&&MAX_ORGS>list) ,  in this case im getting segment fault again.

Comment: @SrinivasThanneeru look at the answer again: you must call `strtok` **first** with parameter `str` and **then** with `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

`char buf[MAX_LENTHS];`

You have not defined the array size, i. e. `MAX_LENTHS` should be defined like

`#define MAX_LENTHS 25`

And as Paul R says in his comment you also need to initialize your array of character pointers

`char *options[MAX_ORGS];`

with something .

Comment: Nah, if it compiles, then it must be defined. It's rather 1. what Paul R. pointer out in his comment, 2. that OP - following the usual bad practice - hasn't really posted the full code.

Comment: @H2CO3 Then I guess , OP deserves a -1 too :)